# I want to know the meaning of "represents a claim"

Tags: meaning, word-request

> A stock is a type of security that signifies ownership in a *corporation* and represents a claim on part of the the organisations assets and earnings.

Here I want to know the meaning  of "represents a claim" because represent has multiple meanings but the usage of the word doesn't go with the meaning of the word. Please explain properly thank you.

Comment: I've changed your image to text. Please don't paste images of text. They  can't be searched or indexed and they are useless for blind people.  Could you mention the source of your quote. It appears to be from a dictionary.

Comment: Ahmed, please do as James K has asked.  Include your quotes in text and tell us where the quotes came from.  [You have already been asked to include text](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/165405/#comment330650_165405) previously, and other users have been [editing your questions for some time](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/165032/revisions) to fix the problem.  We'd appreciate it if you could make sure you do this yourself in future questions.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> 2 Constitute; amount to.
>
> ‘this figure represents eleven per cent of the company's total sales’

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/represent